# Android ListView with padding

Tags: android, android-listview

Someone posted a hint, but I can't find it again.

If you use a `ListView` and it can have padding. You can setup the top/bottom padding to scroll up/down and the scrollbar should ignore the padding.

Does someone know, where I can find this hint?

Comment: What do you mean by scrollbar ignoring the padding ? The scrollbar shows the content in the padded area once we start scrolling ?

Comment: Are you adding padding to ListView cells or ListView itself?

Comment: @vishalv2050 The scrollbar should not be near the `ListView`. It should stay at the most right place.

Comment: @MichalŽídek At the moment, this is my layout file: https://github.com/mars3142/toaster/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/toaster.xml - You can see the app in action: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mars3142.android.toaster

Comment: Try to set your ListView this properties : android:clipToPadding="false"

Answer (score 4):

use `cliptopadding="false"` in listview to ignore the padding when scroling.

check this https://plus.google.com/+JavierPardo/posts/EoWCuGvYR27

Comment: This one was the post, I was searching for. Many thanks.